# How to migrate product images before using Data Migaration tool from magento 1 to magento 2

Tags: product-images, media-images, data-migration-tool, magento2.4.1, magento1.9.0.1

I wish to migrate data from magento 1 to magento 2 using data migration tool.

I know the procedure for migration using data migration tool.

But i am having doubt on, how to migrate the product images &other media files from magento 1 to magento 2.

I have copied the media folder from magento 1 and replaced it in magento 2 pub/media folder.

Before start data migration, can anyone guide me how do i migrate product or other images to magento 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already manually uploaded images, they will automatically map.

Comment: more info at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-plan.html#step-4-start-your-migration

Answer (score 1):

Magento's Devdoc suggests the steps to migrate media from Magento 1 to Magento 2 to be:

- Log in to the Magento 1 Admin Panel as an administrator.
- Click System > Configuration > ADVANCED > System.
- In the right pane, scroll to Storage Configuration for Media.
- From the Select Media Database list, click the name of your media
  storage database.
- Click Synchronize.
- Then, repeat the same steps in your Magento 2 Admin panel.

This information can be found here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-manually.html

Does that answer your question?

Comment: If magento 1 site is Live, will database sync disturb images on Live ???